# Properties of semi norms

Tags: functional-analysis

let $p$ be a semi norm on a subspace $X$. Given set $B=\{ x: p(x)<1\}$, $p = \mu_{B}$.

what I understood is that

take $s$ such that $p(x)<s$. This makes $p(s^{-1} x)<1$. So $s^{-1} x \in B$ which shows that the Minkowski functional $\mu_B(x)\leq s$. We get this from the definition of the Minkowski functional. As $p$ is less than $s$, it can be less than or greater than $\mu_B(x)$. I don't get how we conclude from this that $\mu_B(x) \leq p(x)$.

can someone point out the missing step.

Comment: You have two real numers $a,b$ such that, $a\le s$ for every $s>b$. This implies $a\le b$ (otherewise, consider any $s\in (b,a)$ to get a contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

$\mu_B(x)\leq \inf\{s : p(x) < s\} = p(x)$

or say, take $s_n = p(x)+1/n$ then $p(x) < s_n$ so $\mu_B(x) \leq s_n$, and now since $s_n\to p(x)$ you obtain $\mu_B(x)\leq p(x)$